# Finding the equation of tangent lines where a function has a specified slope

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

A function is defined as

```
f[x_] := 3x^4 + 8x^3 - 24x^2 - 48x + 19
```

I need to find the equation of the tangent lines at the points where the tangent line has a slope of 4. Then I must verify my results by plotting the graph of `y = f(x)` along with the tangent lines in a range which includes the x-coordinates I have found.

I know that I must set `f[x]` and `f'[x]` equal to 4 in order to find the x-coordinates, but I have no idea of how to implement that in *Mathematica*.

Any help would be extremely appreciated!.

Comment: You have a single variable equation, how can you set f[x] and f'[x] equal to 4?

Comment: Lookup the functions `Solve`, `D`, `Plot`.

Comment: [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) and [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) are your friends.

Comment: @Algohi I think he intended to refer to the derivative only given the text above.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries even the derivative will not general an equation for certain slop (4). It is only 3 x values for f'[x]==4.

Comment: @Algohi Don't see the problem. That's precisely what the OP was looking for: "point**s** where the tangent line has a slope of 4"

Answer (score 2):

```
f[x_] := 3 x^4 + 8 x^3 - 24 x^2 - 48x + 19
s = 4; (*slope*)

xs = x /. NSolve[f'[x] == s, x](*here are the x values where f'[x]=4*)

lines = s (x - xs) + f[xs] (*here are the tangents*)

Plot[{lines, f[x]}, {x, Min[xs], Max[xs]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you will find a step-by-step solution helps you to understand how to approach a problem of this type.

The function which defines the curve.

```
f[x_] := 3 x^4 + 8 x^3 - 24 x^2 - 48 x + 19
```

The function giving the slope of the curve.

```
slope[x_] = D[f[x], x]
```

> ```
> -48 - 48 x + 24 x^2 + 12 x^3
> ```

Finding the `x` values for which the slope is 4.

```
xPts = x /. NSolve[slope[x] == 4, x]
```

> ```
> {-2.86789, -0.869623, 1.73751}
> ```

The `y` values for those `x` points.

```
yPts = f /@ xPts
```

> ```
> {-26.4971, 39.0466, -67.5495}
> ```

A function that gives the form of a line of slope 4 passing a point `{x0, y0}`.

```
y[x0_, y0_] := y0 + 4. (x - x0)
```

The expressions for the three tangent lines.

```
lines = MapThread[y, {xPts, yPts}] // Expand
```

> ```
> {-15.0255 + 4. x, 42.5251 + 4. x, -74.4996 + 4. x}
> ```

Coordinates of the points of tangency. Want to show these points on the plot.

```
pts = Transpose @ {xPts, yPts};
```

The plot

```
Plot[{f[x], lines}, {x, -4, 3},
  Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point[pts]}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: A good answer, but perhaps too much for a question that looks like typical homework. I may be mistaken, but I thought that in a Meta discussion about this the general opinion was that we should provide hints only and not spell out the answer.